# Accessing struct fields from assembly block

Tags: solidity, struct, assembly

Say we have the following structure:

```
struct MyStruct {
  uint256 x;
  uint256 y;
}
```

and that it is passed as an argument to some function. Inside that function, we have `assembly` block from where we try to access `x` and `y`:

```
function myFunc(MyStruct memory data) internal view returns (bool) {
  // (...)
  assembly {
    let args := mload(0x40);
    mstore(args, data.x);
    mstore(args, data.y);
    // (...)
  }
  // (...)

}
```

And the compilation fails with:

```
Error: CompileError: ParsedContract.sol:404:28: ParserError: Expected ')' but got '.'
            mstore(args, data.x)
```

Is it not allowed? Is there any workaround? I want to avoid creating temporary `uint256` fields to avoid additional gas expenses.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible `mload(data)` should be the first field, and `mload(add(data, 0x20))` the second, etc.

Comment: @Ismael I had no idea `mload` allows for this. Is it the same for a nested structure? `struct MyStruct {point x, point y}` and `struct point { uint256 x, uint256 y}` ? I am trying to do it the same way with `mload(data)`, `mload(add(data, 0x20))`, then `0x40`, `0x60` but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ismael said, it is possible by using `mload(data)`, here is an example you can test in remix:

**Simple struct**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test {

    struct MyStruct {
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
    }

    function testFunc() public pure returns (uint, uint) {
        MyStruct memory data1 = MyStruct(5,7);
        return myFunc(data1);
    }

    function myFunc(MyStruct memory data) internal pure returns (uint256 _z, uint _w) {
        assembly {
            _z := mload(data)
            _w := mload(add(data,0x20))
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Nested struct**

Answering to your comment, it is possible for a nested struct too. Now you need to load the position where the struct starts.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test {

    struct MyStruct {
        Point x;
        Point y;
    } 

    struct Point {
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
    }

    function testFunc() public pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        MyStruct memory data1 = MyStruct(Point(3,5), Point(7,9));
        return myFunc(data1);
    }

    function myFunc(MyStruct memory data) internal pure returns (uint256 _x, uint256 _y, uint256 _u, uint256 _v) {
        assembly {

            let first_point := mload(data)
            _x := mload(first_point)
            _y := mload(add(first_point,0x20))

            let second_point := mload(add(data,0x20))
            _u := mload(second_point)
            _v := mload(add(second_point,0x20))

            /** Same as above but summarized
            _x := mload(mload(data))
            _y := mload(add(mload(data),0x20))
            _u := mload(add(mload(data),0x40))
            _v := mload(add(mload(data),0x60))
            */
        }
    }
}
```