# Is it possible to access struct field from in-line assembly (Yul) when using ABIEncoderV2?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, assembly, abiencoderv2

Is it possible to access struct field from Yul? Ideally it could look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Sample {
    struct S {
        uint256 n;
        bytes b;
    }
    function foo(S memory s) external {
        uint256 len;
        assembly {
            len := mload(s.b);
        }
    }
}
```

If no, then what is the best way to access `s.b` fiels?

1. Define variable in solidity: `bytes memory localB = s.b;`
2. Some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using the `mload` opcode:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Sample {
    
    struct S {
        uint256 n;
        bytes b;
    }
    
    function foo(S memory s) external pure returns (uint256 _x, bytes memory _y) {
        assembly {
            _x := mload(s)
            _y := mload(add(s,0x20))
        }
    }
}
```

To test the function in Remix, you can use the following tuple: `[1, "0xaa00ff"]`.

Comment: Thanks! It works although not as convenient as possible since it is hard to manually calculate offsets for the struct field when struct is more complicated.

Comment: @VitalyDrogan Yes. In case you are interested, in the following question you can see the same method applied to a nested struct: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77238/accessing-struct-fields-from-assembly-block